# Prevent caching Angular 2 with SystemJS loader

Tags: angular, webpack, systemjs

Is there a way to prevent browser caching using Angular 2 and SystemJS as its module loader, without placing template.clear() for each component? I have read that converting to webpack fixes this because it has its own cache buster, should I just use it as my module loader?